# Vuex: Should I update state before the user hits the save button?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am currently using vuex for my vue.js project. For simplicity, let's say it's a blog. When clicking on the "Create New Blog" button, I don't know if I should **add the new, empty blog object to state and update changes there** or if I should **track changes within the component and only modify state once a user hits the save button**. Clicking on the save button in this case will save data to my database.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="blog in blogs">
      {{blog.name}}
    </div>
    <button @click="createNewBlog">Create New Blog</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    blogs: [{name:"blog1"},{name:"blog2"}] 
    //When I click on the create new blog button, should I push a 
    new, empty blog object here and update it through v-model or should 
    I track changes within the component with v-model and only update state 
    once the user clicks the save button?
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I already have a way to manage state with vuex (vuex-map-fields is the package I use). I wanted to know if it's better structurally to add to my state before a user saves to the database or after. Thank you for your comment tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing will depend on your use case but given this is a simple blog it makes sense to track changes at a component level using v-model then dispatching the new blog information (kept in local component data) to Vuex once the user clicks the save button.